# Column number of matching string in column

Tags: text-processing

I know this seems very simple but I can't get it to work or find a functional option.

Linux UBUNTU OS, bash script

I need to Identify a column number based on a string (there will always be a varying number of columns to search through)

Example input:

```
STRING="Boo"
Hi Boo Jiggy
```

Example Output:

```
2
```

Comment: What if more than one column contains the string?  Do you want to search for substrings?

Comment: No, in this case I know only one column will contain the string, I just don't know which column that will be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ string=Boo
$ echo 'Hi Boo Jiggy' | awk -v b="$string" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == b) { print i } }}'
2
```

We pass your search string as an awk parameter and then loop through each field in the input.  If the current field is equal to the search parameter we print it's number.

Note: this will find more than one string if they exist but will not work for substrings.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks Jesse. I had made some attempts in awk myself but had failed miserably, I always prefer to use awk where possible... i'm just not very good at it

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` and `grep`:

```
string=Boo
echo "Hi Boo Jiggy" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -nw "$string" | cut -d':' -f1
```

---

Note, that unlike @Jesse's version, this variant is not line-aware.
So,

```
echo 'Hi
Boo Jiggy' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -nw "$string" | cut -d':' -f1
```

will output 2, while @Jesse's version will output 1.
I don't know if this matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've just put solution in the script. Maybe you find it helpful:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$1" ] && exit 0

value="$(head -n1 "$1" | grep -Eo '".*"')"
column="$(sed '1d' "$1" | awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == '$value') print i }')"

echo "Column: $column"
```

Example:

```
yurij@opensuse-leap65:~/trash/awk> cat example.txt 
String="Boo"
Hi Boo Jiggy

yurij@opensuse-leap65:~/trash/awk> ./process.sh ./example.txt 
Column: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'put .words.grep(/Boo/, :k);'
1 3
```

Above takes input from `STDIN` and uses a Regex matcher to `Boo`. Raku code returns the whitespace separated column of each match, line-by-line (no matches on a line are indicated by a blank line in the return).

Matching zero-indexed columns are returned. (To return one-indexed columns, add `.map(* + 1)` to the end of the code). If you want to abstract the string out of the Raku code proper, declare it as an environment variable:

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | env string="Boo" raku -ne 'put .words.grep(/<{ %*ENV<string> }>/, :k)'
1 3
```

Works great for files too:

```
~$ env string="Boo" raku -ne 'put .words.grep(/<{ %*ENV<string> }>/, :k)' Hi_Boo_Jiggy_Boo.txt
1 3
```

Finally, if you're sure you only have one match per line--or you only want the first matching column returned--then add an indexing `.[0]` (or `[0]`) to the end of code.

https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2020/07/msg9004.html
https://raku.org