# Column number of containing a string in column

Tags: text-processing, awk

Related to this question,
[Column number of matching string in column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524186/column-number-of-matching-string-in-column)

I want to get the column number in which a certain string is contained.

They did not work below,

```
string=Bo*
echo 'Hi Boo Jiggy' | awk -v b="$string" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == b) { print i } }}'
```

nor

```
string=*oo
echo 'Hi Boo Jiggy' | awk -v b="$string" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == b) { print i } }}'
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In `string=Bo*` - what is the `*` supposed to represent? In a string it should be the literal char `*`, none of which are present in your input but you appear to be wanting to use it as a regexp where `Bo*` would mean `B` followed by 1 or more `o`s but then you're also trying to use `string=*oo` where a `*` at the start is undefined behavior for a regexp. Please [edit] your question to state what you expect `Bo*` and `*oo` to match. I suspect you want a regexp match but are trying to use globbing instead of regexp notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `~` for a regexp like match, not `==`

```
 string=Bo*
 echo 'Hi Boo Jiggy' |
 awk -v b="$string" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ b) { print i } }}'
```

output

```
2
```

---

As pointed out in comment `*oo` is undefined as a regexp (while valid for shell expansion).

to reuse code above, string must be initaliazed with a dot.

```
string=.*oo
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Did not know "~". Perfectly worked.

Comment: That's finding the column in which a string that matches a regexp appears, not the column in which a string appears. Using a variable named `string` and then treating it as a regexp instead of a string is confusing at best. That would also fail (or at least be undefined behavior) for the OPs second case of `string=*oo`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

OR

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'put .words.grep(/Bo./, :k)'
1 3
```

OR

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'my regex R { Bo. }; put .words.grep(/<R>/, :k)'
1 3
```

OR

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | env string="Bo." raku -ne 'put .words.grep(/<{ %*ENV<string> }>/, :k)'
1 3
```

As noted in the comments by @Ed_Morton, it's not entirely clear what the OP intends `*` star to represent. In Regex notation, star is 'zero-or-more' instances of an exemplary character. So `Bo*` matches `Boo`, but not `Bob`.

I suspect that the OP wants `Bo` followed by **ANY** character, and that would be `Bo.` in Regex notation. To demonstrate the difference, the following examples show the difference between Regex-matching `igg*` and `igg.`:

```
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'say .words.match(/igg*/)'
｢igg｣
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'say .words.match(/igg./)'
｢iggy｣

~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'my regex R { igg* }; say .words.match(/<R>/)'
｢igg｣
 R => ｢igg｣
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | raku -ne 'my regex R { igg. }; say .words.match(/<R>/)'
｢iggy｣
 R => ｢iggy｣

~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | env string="igg*" raku -ne 'say .words.match(/<{ %*ENV<string> }>/)'
｢igg｣
~$ echo "Hi Boo Jiggy Boo" | env string="igg." raku -ne 'say .words.match(/<{ %*ENV<string> }>/)'
｢iggy｣
```

See URL below for further examples.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711393/227738
https://raku.org

Comment: Thank you so much!! So helpful!